# How do you return from 'gf' in Vim

Tags: vim, editor

I am using Vim for windows installed in Unix mode. Thanks to this site I now use the `gf` command to go to a file under the cursor.

I'm looking for a command to either:

1. return to the previous file (similar
   to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for ctags), or
2. remap `gf`
   to automatically launch the new file
   in a new window.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: CTRL-O to go to an older position in jump list,
<Tab> or CTRL-I to go to a newer position.

Comment: @g33kz0r the mnemonic would be O = OUT, I = IN  => Ctrl - O brings you out, Ctrl brings you in. If every jump is like going through a door, that is.

Comment: CTRL-O will jump to last visited position, this is annoying when the new file has been searched in. I prefer Shift-Ctrl-6 (in my case Ctrl-6 don't work)

Comment: I think paxdiablo's answer is better. :e# goes just one step back(even when we opend file or directory). ctrl-o goes to the first file.

Answer (score 84):

I frequently use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> for this.

It's handy because it allows me to quickly jump back and forth between the two files.

Answer (score 53):

You might want to use `CTRL-W gf` to open the file in a new tab.

You can close the newly opened file as always with `:bd`, or use `CTRL-6` and other usual ways of changing buffers.

Comment: tab is more convenient than buffer for me, and using `nnoremap gf <C-W>gf` to open in a new tab may be better.

Answer (score 16):

Use gf to descend into a file and use :bf to get back

Comment: I had two windows open in a tab and this just opened the second window in the first instead of jumping back to the previous buffer.

Answer (score 15):

Just use `:e#` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> - that basically says to edit the last (most recent) file.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> is one.

`:e#↲` is another.

Comment: The shift is not necessary. Stop abusing your fingers.

Comment: Um. I'm kind of an old timer. Ctrl-6 wouldn't work with vi on the Wyse terminal I used to have at work years ago. See, some things remain etched. And not using Shift in this combo would hardly make a difference to my total finger abuse. Hey, at least you tried your best. HTH. HAND.

Comment: This switches to what's called the [*alternate file*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#alternate-file).

Answer (score 8):

I got <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to work.
It's quite depressing that I've spent so long perfecting maps for these commands only to discover that there are built-in versions.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the answer to part 2 of your question, but I can help with part 1. Use

```
:e#
```

Vim maintains a list of files (buffers) that it's editing. If you type

```
:buffers
```

it will list all the files you are currently editing. The file in that list with a % beside it is the current file. The one with the # beside it is the alternate file. :e# will switch between the current and alternate file. Rather than type that much, I map F2 to :e# so I can easily flip between the current and alternate files. I map the command to F2 by adding this to .vimrc

```
nmap `<F2> :e#<CR>`
```

Comment: I don't think you want to use :e# because that could potentially reload the file. :b# does the equivalent without this problem.

Comment: Good point. That switches to the other buffer without reloading it.

Answer (score 4):

When you open a new file (with *gf* or *:n* or another command) the old file remains in a buffer list. You can list open files with *:ls*

If you want to navigate easily between buffers in vim, you can create a mapping like this:

```
nmap <M-LEFT> :bN<cr>
nmap <M-RIGHT> :bn<cr>
```

Now you can switch between buffers with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

The complete documentation on mappings is here:

```
:help map.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

See [:help alternate-file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#alternate-file).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your **gf** command but I imagine it uses the **:e** or **:find** command.
Assuming that this is correct, simply replace the **:e** or **:find** with **:new** (or **:vnew** for a vertical split) and the file will open in a new window instead of the same one.

e.g.

```
"Switch between header and cpp
nmap ,s :find %:t:r.cpp<CR>
nmap ,S :new %:t:r.cpp<CR>
nmap ,h :find %:t:r.h<CR>
nmap ,H :new %:t:r.h<CR>
nmap ,F :new =expand("<cfile>:t")<CR><CR>
nmap ,d :new =expand("<cfile>")<CR><CR>
```

Comment: `gf` is built-in. It belongs to all of us. :-)