# Unable to move fast between files in Vim

Tags: vim, performance, editing

I have the following in my .Zshrc

```
. /Users/Masi/bin/Zsh/prompt
```

I need run the following code to access the file from .zshrc

```
    Ctrl-Z 
    vim ~/bin/Zsh/prompt
```

I tried to do the same unsuccessfully by first highlighting the path in visual mode and running

```
:'<,'>!vim
```

**How can you move fast between files in Vim?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `gf` command in Vim, which opens the file that is named at the cursor position. This command opens the file in the same window, replacing whatever file you were previously editing. If you want to open a new window with the file under the cursor, use ^Wf.

See also the question [How do you return from 'gf' in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133626/how-do-you-return-from-gf-in-vim) for more information on file navigation.

Comment: I get the following error message when I try to use gf: Not an editor command: OpenLocationTab <cfile>. Your other command then again works.

Answer (score 4):

If you have vim open, you can open a file for editing using the `:e <filepath>` command.

If you want to have multiple files open simultaneously in the same vim session, you can use windows. You can open a new window with `Ctrl-W n`, then use `:e <filepath>` to open the file in the new window. It's probably better for you to find a tutorial for how to use windows than for me to do a poor job explaining how here. They're not too difficult to use though.

Another alternative is to have a separate vim session for each file, then to cycle through them as needed using job processing. I'm not familiar with the zsh syntax, but in bash, you can press `Ctrl-Z` to pause the currently running job and return to the command line, and resume a job with `fg %n` where n is the job number you want to resume. So you can use these to open file 1 with vim, pause vim, open up file 2 with a new vim session, pause it, and alternate back and forth with pausing and foregrounding as necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Instead of Ctrl-W n, i find :vsplit and :split easier to remember.

Comment: I know remember the reason why I did not use the Window button. I have the following bug in my Screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809935/unable-to-solve-a-bug-in-vims-tlist-with-screen/809975#809975   My Vim gets upset when I have vertical split.