# Jumping back to a previously opened file in Vim

Tags: vim, split, ctags

While using Vim I'll sometimes want to look at a function definition or a struct definition, so I'll use `C-]` to jump to it. However, there are a few problems I run into. First off, I don't know how to jump back easily. It appears the previous file I was in closes and I'm now in the new one. Is there a way to jump back, or keep a stack of open files that I can pop back to or something?

Another thing I've noticed that when I have a change in the current file I need to save it because, like a mentioned a moment ago, my current file is being closed before the next one opens.

And sometimes I want to view my current code and my header at once. Is there a way open the tag definition in a split?

Comment: Related but not duplicate: [How do you return from gf in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/133626/834176).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add

```
set hidden
```

to you vimrc. It'll allow you switch files without saving them. I think this is one of 'must have' options.

Use <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> to jump back to previous locations which were autosaved in a jumplist.

```
:h jumplist
```

Answer (score 7):

To jump back from C-], use C-T. The `:tags` command shows the current stack.

Set the `autowrite` option to automatically save what you're doing before jumping to a new file.

Use C-W C-] to open the tag in a new window.

Finally, `:help tags` is the section in help that explains all this and more.

Answer (score 3):

Another useful feature that comes handy is the uppercase marks. These marks are not local to a buffer and can be used to jump to them from across files. If you mark the line as say "A" using mA command before starting a long and arduous jumping around task, you can finally return back to the original position quickly by typing 'A or `A.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a few vim extensions that make this even simpler.

lusty-juggler and lusty-explorer

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2050
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890

These require that vim was built with +ruby.

```
% vim --version | grep +ruby
```

They're very useful for staying in vim and jumping between files.