# VIM recently edited files history

Tags: vim, history

Is there a history of files edited in VIM that persists between
vim sessions, e.g. last 20 opened files. 
I tend to edit the same .conf files and I have to navigate to them each time
of course they are spread all over the filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As standard, no, but there's a plugin [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521) that adds this functionality.  [This one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2606) also mentions recent file history on the page, so it may provide an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Actually this behavior IS built in. With default settings you should be able to use the `:oldfiles` command to view a numbered list of recent files. Then use `:e #>4` for example, to edit number 4 in the list. Or `:browse oldfiles`, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29688194/1390430).

Answer (score 3):

As [this answer indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728413/461834), one may use `ctrl-o` to jump backward in file history. It will automatically open previously edited files.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider giving [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) a chance (if you are not using it now).
It provides the command:

```
:CtrlPMRUFiles
```

that let's you select previous opened files. That is besides all the other cool stuff.
I was using the MRU plugin mentioned by @DrAI but once I started using ctrlp I just use that one.

Another popular plugin that provides a mru capability is [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:marks` to navigate between recently used files.