# How do I open files from my oldfiles list in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, I can type `:oldfiles` to see a list of files I've previously edited.  Awesome feature!

But now I want to open one or more files from that list into a buffer.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use `:help oldfiles`, you will find the command `:browse oldfiles` which should do what you want.

```
:bro[wse] ol[dfiles][!]
                        List file names as with |:oldfiles|, and then prompt
                        for a number.  When the number is valid that file from
                        the list is edited.
                        If you get the |press-enter| prompt you can press "q"
                        and still get the prompt to enter a file number.
                        Use ! to abandon a modified buffer. |abandon|
                        {not when compiled with tiny or small features}
```

Comment: Nice!  Any way to open more than one file at a time?  Say `2,3,4` or `2-4`?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben, I don't know of one but you could probably write one using vimscript.

Answer (score 30):

Once you are at the bottom of the list you are supposed to press `:` and issue a command, using this "weird" notation:

```
:command #<91
```

where `command` could be any edit-like command (`:edit`, `:tabedit`, `:split`, `:vsplit`, `:next`, `:args`, etc.) and `#<` means "old file number…".

To edit entry 91, use:

```
:e #<91
```

To edit entries 18, 42 and 93, use:

```
:args #<18 #<42 #<93
```

Comment: More simple it would be just enter a number in the list to edit file

Comment: @AlexShwarc, `:browse oldfiles`, as in the accepted answer, does just that but it is less flexible than plain `:oldfiles` by a very large margin.

Comment: This is in my view the correct answer becasue it explains clearly how to open the file. The other answers given so far do not

Answer (score 0):

Nearly 8 years later I stumbled on this old question and thought I'd update with what I do now (which is miles ahead of where this question ended).

I use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) and just type `:History` and then get an awesome fuzzy search over `:oldfiles` !