# Where can i find the plugin which opens the file under cursor in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins

I am referring to this particular plugin 
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor

I tried searching in vim site but i am not able to find it. Googled a lot as well , but no luck.

Can anyone point me to the correct link?

Comment: can you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a plugin. This behavior is built into vim. Simply position your cursor over the filename and type `gf`.

If the current file has unsaved changes, you will see an error at the bottom of your window stating so, and the file will not open. Likewise if the file does not exist.

Comment: Thanks Jeff it worked. How do i switch back to the original file?

Comment: Ctrl-O See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1728413/353278), which says you can `set hidden` to jump back and forth between *unsaved* files. sounds useful.

Comment: @Kelly, add `set hidden` to your `~/.vimrc`, use `<C-^>` to switch to the previous buffer and, above all, read `:h buffers`.

Comment: Try to keep distance from netrw as much as possible, install this https://github.com/tyru/open-browser.vim or any other plugin or custom code in your `vimrc`/`init.vim` and for your own health "keep distance from netrw" (look at this for example https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4738, after reading that you may think you should keep distance from vim itself too, in that case you may consider installing Neovim, Neovim is expected to eventually get rid of netrw)

Comment: @Sassan there is no mention of netrw here... Maybe you posted in the wrong thread?

Comment: @Jeff if you run `map gx` you'll see `n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX` which means `gx` is implemented with netrw, sorry should've mention how it's related

Comment: @sassan this post is about gf, not gx

Comment: Sorry, I'm not deleting my comments so that people who read your answer get warned about `gx` too as a bonus, `gf` is fine.